# Julia - dataframe - How to force cast as a vector/multiple line value a scalar results using by()

Tags: dataframe, casting, julia

Long and winding road, exploring DataFrames.jl and one more question.

I am trying to force cast a function returning a scalar to map back to the entire vector.
I am not sure this is entirely clear so let me exemplify :

Lets say I am running the following  (and now canonical) example

```
df = DataFrame(grp = rand(["a","b"], 100), x= rand(100), y = rand(100), z=rand(100));
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => (x) -> sum(x))
```

```
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ grp    │ result  │
│     │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ b      │ 30.431  │
│ 2   │ a      │ 19.9667 │
```

I get the sum of x, for each of the group. All good. But for some reason I want to have this sum of each group casted for each of the line in the dataset

I found the following hack

```
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => (x) -> x.-x.+sum(x))
```

Giving exactly what I expect

```
│ Row │ grp    │ result  │
│     │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ b      │ 30.431  │
│ 2   │ b      │ 30.431  │
│ 3   │ b      │ 30.431  │
⋮
│ 98  │ a      │ 19.9667 │
│ 99  │ a      │ 19.9667 │
│ 100 │ a      │ 19.9667 │
```

Now, I essentially force a vector aspect in the function to make it happen, (I also do it in the most inelegant way).

**My question is : Is there with by() a correct/nicer way to force a function returning a scalar to map back to the original vector ?**

In my opinion this would be very helpful and also help to address the following situations.

```
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => (x) -> sum(x),result2= (:x) => (x) -> mean(x)) # works returns 2 lines 
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => (x) -> sum(x),result2= (:x) => (x) -> x.-5) # doesnt work (scalar vs vector)
by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => (x) -> x.-x.+sum(x),result2= (:x) => (x) -> x.-5) # works returns 100 lines
```

I am sure I am missing something any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `by` does not make restrictions on the number of rows a transforming function should return. The only restriction is that if there are multiple functions passed they must return the same number of rows.

Here is what you could alternatively do:

```
by(df, :grp,result= :x => x -> fill(sum(x), length(x)))
```

A general approach you can use, which is a bit slower, but more flexible is to use `by` in the following way (I am rewriting your example `by(df, :grp,result= (:x) => (x) -> sum(x),result2= (:x) => (x) -> x.-5)` that does not work):

```
by(df, :grp) do sdf
    DataFrame(result = sum(sdf.x), result2 = sdf.x .- 5)
end
```

Here you are passing a whole `SubDataFrame` to a grouping function and use the implicit broadcasting functionality of `DataFrame` constructor.

Your specific example also could be written as:

```
by(df, :grp, :x => x -> DataFrame(result = sum(x), result2 = x .- 5))
```

which is a specific solution using the fact that in both generated columns you use the same column from source data frame for computations.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help on the last 3 questions. Have a good Sunday (or whats left of it !)